# How does the compiler generate the instance of the function when I'm using template parameters in some conditions?

Tags: c++, function, templates, cuda, instance

I need to know what will the function instance look like after the compilation in the following code when the blockSize will be 128.

```
template <unsigned int blockSize>
__global__ void reduce6(int *g_idata, int *g_odata, unsigned int n) {
extern __shared__ int sdata[];
unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*(blockSize*2) + tid;
unsigned int gridSize = blockSize*2*gridDim.x;
sdata[tid] = 0;
while (i < n) { sdata[tid] += g_idata[i] + g_idata[i+blockSize]; i += gridSize; }
__syncthreads();
if (blockSize >= 512) { if (tid < 256) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 256]; } __syncthreads(); }
if (blockSize >= 256) { if (tid < 128) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 128]; } __syncthreads(); }
if (blockSize >= 128) { if (tid < 64) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 64]; } __syncthreads(); }
if (tid < 32) warpReduce(sdata, tid);
if (tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}
```

Will it be the following?

```
  __global__ void reduce6(int *g_idata, int *g_odata, unsigned int n) {
    extern __shared__ int sdata[];
    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*(blockSize*2) + tid;
    unsigned int gridSize = blockSize*2*gridDim.x;
    sdata[tid] = 0;
    while (i < n) { sdata[tid] += g_idata[i] + g_idata[i+blockSize]; i += gridSize; }
    __syncthreads();

    if (tid < 64) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 64]; } __syncthreads();

    if (tid < 32) warpReduce(sdata, tid);
    if (tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "after  the compilation" I think you mean "what can I consider the code to look like after simple optimisations based on my template parameter". If this is not the case, I'll delete this answer.

If this is the case, your given conceptual code is nearly correct. You've missed the replacement in your indexing calculations. Of course, the compiler is free to do what it likes, and it's dependent on options, but this is what it *could* do, and in this specific case probably what it *would* do.

```
 __global__ void reduce6(int *g_idata, int *g_odata, unsigned int n) {
     extern __shared__ int sdata[];
     unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
     unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*(256) + tid;
     unsigned int gridSize = 256*gridDim.x;
     sdata[tid] = 0;
     while (i < n) { sdata[tid] += g_idata[i] + g_idata[i+128]; i += gridSize; }
     __syncthreads();

     if (tid < 64) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 64]; } __syncthreads();

     if (tid < 32) warpReduce(sdata, tid);
     if (tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
   }
```

By giving the compiler information about the value of blockSize using the template, you can reduce the number of operations that the kernel *needs* to do, though whether they are actually done is up to the compiler.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, it depends on the interpretation of the question. I've chosen to interpret it as "what code would I expect to compile to the same code as the templated code?" (the given example supports my interpretation in my opinion). The only strictly correct answer to the original question "what will the function instance look like after the compilation?" is would be "binary", which would of course be dependent on OS/versions/options/other.

Comment: Yes I think this is the absolutely right answer. That code is taken from this parallel reduction optimization, check page 26 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf and I wanted to know, what it is good for. So all those if statements are evaluated at compile time so it will not take any time to run thru all of the if statements in run-time, am I right?

Anwers this last question and I will makr your answer as correct.

Comment: Exactly. The compiler can optimise based on what is now a compile-time constant.

Comment: Thank you, I have downloaded the cuda samples, where I could try out this reduction with and without templates and it is improve the run-time time, but if I implemented it in my algorithm it had no improvement. Even if I tried small blockSize.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I interpreted your question as "what will the code look like since the template non-type parameter is known? What is its use?"*

It doesn't quite make sense to visualize what you're asking at source-code level but one could make some assumptions that a compiler (depending on how this is internally implemented, with a LLVM front-end that immediately gets optimized it should happen right away), since blockSize == 128, **will not** generate code for the following parts:

```
template <unsigned int blockSize>
__global__ void reduce6(int *g_idata, int *g_odata, unsigned int n) {
extern __shared__ int sdata[];
unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*(blockSize*2) + tid;
unsigned int gridSize = blockSize*2*gridDim.x;
sdata[tid] = 0;
while (i < n) { sdata[tid] += g_idata[i] + g_idata[i+blockSize]; i += gridSize; }
__syncthreads();
--- no code for this section ---
--- no code for this section ---

--- skipped if check ---
if (tid < 64) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 64]; } __syncthreads();

if (tid < 32) warpReduce(sdata, tid);
if (tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}
```

again: this should be visualized at code-generated level since there might be other optimizations triggered by the template parameter evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, it's implementation-dependent, but I would expect a decent compiler to optimize out the constant conditions, so I your guess is most likely right.

Though I don't know if nvcc would do it, and the only way to check is to see the assembly code.